# How do I combine all lines in a text file into a single line?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to get all lines in a text into one line. I'm a beginner at coding trying to learn by doing. I've spent four hours trying to solve this problem. I know there's a simple solution to this problem. Here's what I've been trying.

```
sed -e 'N;s/\n//' myfile.txt #Does nothing

sed -e :a -e N -e 's/\n/ /' -e ta myfile.txt #output all messed up and I can't make head nor tail of the syntax

cat myfile.txt | tr -d '\n' > myfile.txt # Deletes all lines
```

Here's the text file:

```
500212
262578-4-4
23200
GRIFFITH LABORATORIES LTD
GRIFFITH LABORATORIES
SOUTH DUBLIN COUNTY COUNCIL
OFFICE
OFFICE (INDUSTRIAL)
List Rateable
2 Pineview Industrial Estate
Firhouse Road
Knocklyon
31 Dec 2007
01 Jan 2008"
```

I can't figure out where I've gone wrong....

Answer (score 46):

`tr` as you used it *should* work and is the simplest -- you just need to **output to another file**. If you use the input file as output, the result is an empty file as you observed;

```
cat myfile.txt | tr -d '\n' > oneline.txt
```

You need to remember some editors terminate a line with `\r\n`. For that case, use

```
cat myfile | tr -d '\r\n'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it's still not working. I know it's saomething basic and simple. The command you gave deleted all lines. I'm going to post the file 500212
262578-4-4
23200
GRIFFITH LABORATORIES LTD
GRIFFITH LABORATORIES 
SOUTH DUBLIN COUNTY COUNCIL
OFFICE
OFFICE (INDUSTRIAL)
List Rateable
2 Pineview Industrial Estate
Firhouse Road
Knocklyon
31 Dec 2007
01 Jan 2008

Comment: @JOhn: What is the result or error?

Comment: I was going to post by editing my answer. After I used the command the file was blank. It looked like this in the terminal "cat reval_details.asp?Pno=500211.txt | tr -d '\n' > reval_details.asp?Pno=500211.txt". Thanks again.

Comment: @John: **You cannot use the same output file name!!** (see answer). Please try `cat reval_details.asp?Pno=500211.txt | tr -d '\n' > new_reval_details.asp?Pno=500211.txt`

Comment: Sorry about that. The command cat reval_details.asp?Pno=500213.txt | tr -d '\n' > reval_details.asp?Pno=500213.txt
deleted the file. I tried cat reval_details.asp?Pno=500213.txt | tr -d '\n' > newfile.txt. newfile.txt is the same as the old 500213
262578-5-8
7900
PATRICK SPILLANE
SECTOR SECURITY
SOUTH DUBLIN COUNTY COUNCIL
OFFICE
OFFICE (INDUSTRIAL)
List Rateable
5 Pineview Industrial Estate
Firhouse Road
Knocklyon
31 Dec 2007
01 Jan 2008. Cheers

Comment: A better way of doing this would be `tr -d '\n' <input.txt > output.txt` - that avoids the useless use of cat, and uses one less unnecessary pipe.

Comment: It could also be done with `<input.txt tr -d '\n' > output.txt`, if you find that more readable.

Comment: If the input file consists of words, I would not only remove the line-feeds, but to replace them with spaces in order to make the long string more readable: `<input.txt tr '\n' ' ' > output.txt`

Comment: You may also do e.g. `tr '\n' ' '` to replace all newlines with spaces. Otherwise you may end up with one continuous line

Answer (score 9):

**SIMPLE METHOD**

Another method using awk,

```
cat myfile.txt | awk '{print}' ORS=''
```

Output:

> 500212262578-4-423200GRIFFITH LABORATORIES LTDGRIFFITH
>   LABORATORIESSOUTH DUBLIN COUNTY COUNCILOFFICEOFFICE (INDUSTRIAL)List
>   Rateable2 Pineview Industrial EstateFirhouse RoadKnocklyon31 Dec
>   200701 Jan 2008"

**Note:**

**ORS=''** -> ORS(Output Record Separator). (i.e) your field separator, you can have any characters in-between the single quotes as a field separator.
Using this awk method we can include spaces and all characters.

Hope this might help!

Comment: ORS is the Output Record Separator. OFS is the Output  Field Separator. See https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/?ref=binfind.com/web or `man awk`

Comment: The `cat` is still [useless.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score 3):

#### GEDIT:

Search and replace `\n` with a space ' '.
You can get the replace window by going to 'Search'->'Replace'
or via the keybpard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

See screenshot below:

Your original text is on lines 1-14.
The result is on line 16.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way to do this is:

```
paste -s -d:" " test.txt
```

http://ss64.com/bash/paste.html

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to put the label `:a` outside of the main instruction, neither is the `-e` option necessary needed; finally, the `/$/` is superfluous (every line has an EOL character).

Improving other answers, one gets

```
sed -i ':a; N; s/\n/ /; ta' file
```

Which is clearer if written as follows,

```
sed -i ':a
        N
        s/\n/ /
        ta' file
```

The command works as follows:

1. `N` appends the next line to the (multiline) pattern space, which contains the current line already;
2. `s/\n/ /` substitute the newline character `\n` generated by `N` with a space ;
3. `ta` goes to the script line following the label `:a` **as long as the substitution in step 2 was successful**, *i.e.* if the substitution occurred, the execution jumps to step 1 without "hitting" the end of script, *i.e.* **without** reading another line of input.

Note the following;

- `sed` reads the lines of the input file one by one in order, **starting from the 1st line**;
- `:a` is just a label, not a command to be executed;
- `N` is, in principle, executed on any line, but
- `s/\n/ /` (in principle executed on any line) is successful **on any line but the last one**, so
- `ta` makes the end of the script reachable **only when the last line of input is read** (the only line where `s` fails), so
- no further input line is read into the pattern space after the **1st one** is read into it, unless the **last one** is read in, but then there's no further line to read in, and the implicit `p` command is executed.

So the script basically reads in the **1st line** of input and keeps appending the following lines one by one, each time substituting the newline with a space; after the **last line** is appended (and `\n` changed in a space), `N` can't append any line, `s` fails, `ta` is skipped, the end of the script is reached, and the implied `p`rint statement is executed on the current looong 1-line pattern space.

The `-i` option substitutes the input file `file` with the whole 1-line pattern space.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
sed -e :a -e '/$/N; s/\n/\\n/; ta' [filename]
```

http://anandsekar.github.io/joining-all-lines-in-a-file-using-sed/

Comment: Could you give more details / explanation about all these switches ? It can make to understand better why it is working or not.

Answer (score 2):

Python approach:

```
python -c "import sys; print(' '.join([ l.strip() for l in sys.stdin.readlines() ]))" < input.txt
```

AWK:

```
awk '{printf "%s ",$0}' /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were simply forgetting that you needed to tell sed to redirect the output of yourfile.txt to the desired result, newfile.txt. This appears to be the command you need, but only if the files you are trying to merge are not too big for sed's  buffers: `sed -e :a -e N -e 's/\n/ /' -e ta yourfile.txt >newfile.txt`. Credit to [another forum here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/merge-lines-in-a-file-using-sed-191121/), where they discuss sed's capabilities. I have tested the command and it worked for me.

Comment: Actually, *sed* with the `-i` switch will modify the original file *inline*, so there's no need to output to another file. Be careful though!

Comment: I tried sed -e :a -e N -e 's/\n/ /' -e ta reval_details.asp?Pno=500214.txt
 01 Jan 2008addustrial Estate
sed -i :a -e N -e 's/\n/ /' -e ta reval_details.asp?Pno=500214.txt
sed: can't find label for jump to `a'
sed -i :a -e N -i 's/\n/ /' -e ta reval_details.asp?Pno=500214.txt
sed: can't find label for jump to `a'
sed -e :a -e N -i 's/\n/ /' -e ta reval_details.asp?Pno=500214.txt
sed: can't read s/\n/ /: No such file or directory #Any ideas.

Comment: @Mik I've still had no luck but thanks for the reply.

Comment: I copy and pasted your text into a text editor and saved the file then used my sed command and it made it all appear on one line when opened in nano; however if you open out the file using cat in the terminal it will be wrapped and not appear to be just one line, so perhaps that's what's happening. Also, you don't need a' before sed and I think you've added some other unnecessary elements to the command above, so try sed -e :a -e N -e 's/\n/ /' -e ta yourfile.txt >newfile.txt The line is so long it will appear wrapped on screen, however, unless you have a 30+ inch monitor!

Comment: @Mik Cheers for the post. I typed my data into a text editor saved it and ran ' sed -e :a -e N -e 's/\n/ /' -e ta abc.txt >abc1.txt ' and it worked. perfectly. Hallelujah. I then typed ' sed -e :a -e N -e 's/\n/ /' -e ta reval_details.asp?Pno=500215.txt >Pno=500215.txt ' and every line apart from the first had a space added to the start of the line. I appreciate the effort you put in but I think I'll move on to octave and try and process the data there.

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash solution:

```
while read i; do printf '%s ' "$i"; done < file.txt > outfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I'd just open it in vim and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> a few times.

Answer (score 0):

```
vim <your_file>
```

Type within vim and press Enter:

```
:% s/\n/ /g
```

Answer (score 0):

With no subshell or external command calls makes it fairly fast, at least on smaller reads.

```bsh
mapfile -t < file; echo "${MAPFILE[*]}" > file
```

It is possible to achieve the same with `read`.

```bsh
read -rd '' -a a < file; echo "${a[*]}" > file
```